# Write Content To New Window with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a web page with a DIV element in it. When a user clicks "print", I want to print the contents of that div. Please note, I only want to print the contents of the DIV, not the entire page. To attempt this, I decided I would open a new window using JavaScript. I was then going to write the contents of the DIV into the new window. My question is, is this possible with JQuery? If so, how? Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
function printClick() {
  var w = window.open();
  var html = $("#divToPrintID").html();

  // how do I write the html to the new window with JQuery?
}
```

Comment: Here's a similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225558/jquery-new-window-with-content-from-modal-content-on-opener-page

Answer (score 53):

You can use

```
$(w.document.body).html(html);
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ypAsY/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in IE7 for me. Any known issues with that?

Answer (score 6):

Try -

```
var w = window.open();
var html = $("#divToPrintID").html();
w.document.writeln(html);
```

Reference - http://www.javascripter.net/faq/writingt.htm

Comment: For one-liner fans: `window.open().document.writeln($("#divToPrintID").val());`

Answer (score 4):

file1:

```
function find(input){
    return $(input);
}

function printClick() {
  var w = window.open();
  var html = $("#divToPrintID").html();

  // how do I write the html to the new window with JQuery?
}
```

and in the second file do that:

```
var html = window.opener.find("#divToPrintID").html();
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a pretty perfect match of a tutorial for exactly that..
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm

Additionally, you can attact print-only CSS to the page that has everything but what you want turned off.