# write contents in a certain part of new window using jQuery

Tags: jquery, new-window

I have this codes in my projects to open a new window to show and then, print the result table from my first window:

```
$('a.print_btn').click(function(e) {
    var elementId = $(this).attr('id');
    var elementToPrint = $("#report_" + elementId).html();
    var printWin = window.open("print.php?id="+elementId, "Print");
    $(printWin.document.body).html(elementToPrint);
});
```

In this code, #report_elementId points to a fieldset that contains my table information. If I use the code below I can see all table contents:

`alert(elementToPrint);`

So everything is ok so far. But the last line of code does not work and anything don't write in **printWin** window. I don't know why :(

I used [Write Content To New Window with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841100/write-content-to-new-window-with-jquery) for it, but it does not work for me. Help me please.

By the way, I need to write contents to a certain div (`id="myDiv"`). How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  var printWin = window.open("print.php?id="+elementId, "Print");
  $(printWin.document).ready( function() {
     $('div#myDiv').html(elementToPrint); 
  }
```

I assume print.php?id=[something]  does work, ie not ending in a 500 or a 404 error...

As I'm uncertain in what context the ready callback is executed let's try to be more explicit:

```
  var printWin = window.open("print.php?id="+elementId, "Print");
  $(printWin.document).ready( function() {
     $(printWin.document).find('div#myDiv').html(elementToPrint); 
  }
```

Comment: rene, `$('myDiv').html(elementToPrint);` does not work for me :( I don't know why. If I alert `elementToPrint` I can see all html contents, but I don't know why it can not be written

Comment: It seems that I don't have any access to `$('myDiv')`. I tried `$('myDiv').css('background-color','#333');` too. But anything did not happen.

Comment: @Mohammad I added a second example to make sure selection runs the right context

Comment: but this line `$(printWin.document).find('div#myDiv').html(elementToPrint); ` didn't work for me-@rene

Comment: @ubm ask a new question where you follow the guidance in [mcve] to make sure we can see what is different between your case and this one. It could be a security policy, a jquery error, html markup that is wrong etc. There is barely enough info your comment to diagnose what could be wrong.

Comment: @rene I have no permission to ask questions,thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
printWin.body.innerHTML = elementToPrint;
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = elementToPrint;
```