# Display hidden div as content in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube, popup

I am trying to mirror the functionality of the [video player on this page](http://cookware.lecreuset.com/cookware/product_5-1/2-qt.-Round-French-Oven_10151_-1_20002_10138), when you click View a Product Demonstration. It pops up with a new window (not a new tab) where scrolling is disabled and a size is defined.  It is important that my pop-up has this too. A dialog box won't work.

The video I'm using is a YouTube video; I can make the video pop-up by itself from clicking a link on a page.  However, I need to also be able to display other content in the pop-up (images + text) window.

I am new to jQuery so I don't know the best approach to achieve this.  My first thought was that I could put everything in a hidden div, and then make that content display in a new window when an element is clicked, and apply css with the jQuery when clicked to make it display properly.

After researching on SO, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841100/write-content-to-new-window-with-jquery), which sort of works. The problem is that it opens in a new tab, not a new window, and the CSS is lost in the new tab (which I can fix with inline styles, not ideal but I can live with it). I could use this if I could make it a new window instead of tab. [Here is my code in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3D5DE/) and here it is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printClick() {
        var w = window.open();
        var html = $("#video-container").html();
        $(w.document.body).html(html);
    }

    $(function() {
        $("a#video-link").click(printClick);

    });
</script>
```

and then:

```
<div id="product-description">
    <a href="#" id="video-link">
    <img src="cookware-product-demonstration-video.png" alt="View Product Demonstration Video" width="355" height="55" style="padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;" border="0" />
    </a>
</div>
<div id="video-container" style="display: none;>
    <div id="video" style="width: 600px; position: relative; margin: 0px auto;">
        <div id="video-header">
            <img src="logo.gif" height="30" width="120" alt="Company Logo" style="float: left;"/>
            <p style="float: right">Product Demonstration Video</p>
        </div>
        <iframe width="600" height="338" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/yeuCLMppZzc?rel=0"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

But, is this really the best approach? I feel like there must be a better way to do this.  I found a few posts where target="_blank" is added to the href ([example here](http://jsfiddle.net/uh9GY/)), but since I'm not opening a URL this hasn't worked for me so far.

Any help or advice on how to do this is appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Personally, I cannot stand popups.  I find them very annoying, especially when I have multiple windows open.  My suggestion is to use [`jQueryUI's Dialog`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default) and give the illusion of a popup. If you need further info, let me know.

Comment: I agree with you 100% - would much rather do this in a dialog or a modal. I've been tasked with making it "as close to this as possible to maintain a consistent site experience"... the dialog or modal wouldn't have the browser bar at the top though. :\

Comment: I see.... hmm, well I'll be back with an answer for you!

Comment: Sympathetic +1 for exacting requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use a querystring.

Using the function from [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values), have the following on another page:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = 400,
    height = 300;

    //I've constructed it like this to prevent possible embedding errors

   var vid = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/' + getParameterByName("test");
   $('<object width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '">' +
   '<param name="movie" value="' + vid + '" />' +
   '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />' +
   '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />' +
   '<param name="wmode" value="opaque">' +
   '<embed src="' + vid + '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque" /></object>')
   .appendTo($('#div1')); 
});
```

Example of Page 1:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/dirtyd77/rmEvY/5/

Then on another page, use the following:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b1").click(function(){
       var url = 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/dirtyd77/rmEvY/5/show/?test=yeuCLMppZzc';
       window.open(url, '_blank', "height=400,width=450");  //set height and width to make new window
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/tVEBj/1/

Here is a demo of the final product:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/dirtyd77/tVEBj/1/show/

This is how I would possibly go about it, but it is by no means the ***best*** way to.  Hopefully this is what you are looking for.  Let me know if you have any questions! Good luck!

---

**EDIT:**

After some tinkering, I found a way to do this in one page.

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b1").click(function(){
        var win = window.open('', '_blank', "height=400,width=450");
        var width = 400,
        height = 300,
        vid='http://www.youtube.com/v/yeuCLMppZzc';
        var obj = '<object width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '">' +
                            '<param name="movie" value="' + vid + '" />' +
                            '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />' +
                            '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />' +
                            '<param name="wmode" value="opaque">' +
                            '<embed src="' + vid + '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque" /></object>';
        win.document.write(obj);
    });
});
```

DEMO:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/tVEBj/6/

Comment: Thanks! The functionality is just what I'm looking for, but is it possible to do it all on one page instead of making 2 pages? I am plugging this one div and video button into Websphere on a product listing page (not sure if you're familiar). It would be best not to have to make multiple pages...our SEO folks really don't want us creating anymore URLs than necessary.

Comment: thank you! But it still references another URL...is there a way to do this without an external site?

Comment: Yes! This is perfect. Thank you for helping me figure this out...I even added my logo + text to your code. Learning on the job :)  Thank you!!

Comment: @surfbird0713 of course! let me know if you need any other assistance! happy coding!