# Popup a div in a new windows but preserve css and scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm following this example:
[Write Content To New Window with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841100/write-content-to-new-window-with-jquery) to popup a div in a new window. 
The problem is that I also need to include the css and script files.

Code:

```
var w = window.open();
var html = $("#modal").html();

$(w.document.body).html(html);
```

It works fine but looks ugly.

How can I add the css and the js script to the header?

This is working:

```
$(w.document.head).append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin/flexigrid/css/flexigrid.pack.css" />');
```

But this is not:

```
$(w.document.head).append('<script src="plugin/flexigrid/js/flexigrid.js"><\/script>');
```

Comment: You might be better off just creating a new page to open in the popup instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(w.document.head).append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">');
$(w.document.head).append('<script src="scripts.js"><\/script>');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypAsY/1196/

Comment: It works for the css but it doesnt work for the js. Why would that be?

Comment: Escape the closing `script` tag with a backslash (answer updated).

Comment: Oh nevermind. I'll fix it somehow. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your "foo" script works for me. It shows the alert, but when I inspect the sourcecode of the page the script is not there :/.