# How to open the content inside a DIV tag in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('.menu div.profile-btn').on('click', function () {
    $('.mainservice-page').fadeIn(1200);
}
```

The above script opens the contents of the div `.mainservice-page` successfully, but I want to open them in a new tab.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean browser tab?

Comment: Here's a similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841100/write-content-to-new-window-with-jquery

Comment: Did you open any URL or you want to open only content in new tab of browser ? Means this  class "mainservice-page" contains a complete page or just content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do like that :

```
function newWindow_method_1() {
  var wi = window.open();
  var html = $('.mainservice-page').html();
  $(wi.document.body).html(html);
}
OR
function newWindow_method_2() {

  var html = $('.mainservice-page').html();
  window.open(html, "__new", "width=1000,height=1000");

}

$('.menu div.profile-btn').on('click', function () { 
  newWindow_method_1();

 // OR

 // newWindow_method_2();

});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Manoj Srivastava Worked like charm. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @StackOverflowerrr

Comment: Working answer, one question though, if we set some values in html controls in jquery and then we open div in new tab then all values set will show in new tab ?