# Use JavaScript to change background image of a div in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following line to change background of the div Wrapper to an image:

```
$("#wrapper").css("background","url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0");
```

However, Wrapper exists in another page from the function where I am calling this line of code , so when I navigate to the page with Wrapper in it, it has not changed.

Is there anyway I am able to change the background of Wrapper from another page?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JQuery to Access a New Window's DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788480/using-jquery-to-access-a-new-windows-dom)

Comment: Are you navigating to a completely new page with a full post back?

Comment: Then you'll have to put code in the new page that checks something (like, as suggested, a cookie) and adjusts accordingly.

Comment: @LordSnoutimus added an example in my answer - quite simple and straight forward with a cookie ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the values in a cookie, working example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/cEpjc/ :

store it in a cookie on the page you want to set the background :

```
setCookie('background','url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0');
```

then on the "other" page do this :

```
$('#div').css('background',getCookie('background'));
```

For cookie reading and writing you could either use a [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) (thanks @Filip) or basic JavaScript cookie methods :

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}


function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! But since you're already on jQuery I would suggest you give the jQuery Cookie Plugin a run. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie

Comment: @Filip thanks .. i have updated the answer to include the plugin as an alternative ... 1.86 KB though !!!!! ;-)

Comment: I'm making the change on a page before the one with the Wrapper div. How can I set the cookie before even navigating to the page?

Comment: @LordSnoutimus exactly as it says in my answer .... call setCookie on the page where you want to set the background, then getCookie on the page you want to use the background thats been set - cookies are stored on the client and passed to the server each request