# Access Elements in Another Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, element

is it possible to write a javascript to access the elements (knowing their id) in another open window? I want to refresh the page and read some elements' contents.

Comment: are you talking about child window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the content of other tabs in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203530/accessing-the-content-of-other-tabs-in-browser)  -  [Using JQuery to Access a New Window's DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788480/using-jquery-to-access-a-new-windows-dom)

Answer (score 0):

You can totally use sessionStorage ! [Here is the Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

If user direct to next page in same tab, sessionStorage can easily save you data and reuse in next page.

```
// set in page A
window.sessionStorage.setItem('youdata', 'youdata');
// or window.sessionStorage['youdata'] = 'youdata';

// get in page B
var youdata = window.sessionStorage.getItem('youdata');
// or var youdata = window.sessionStorage['youdata'];
```

That's it! very simple!

If you'll open a new tab, you can use localStorage. [Here Is the Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

The usage of localStorage is like the way of sessionStorage.

While do saving information for other pages, these two method only need browsers' support.

Comment: thanks but how can I specify the other window? I cannot see anywhere to specify a window title or a url.

Comment: it will be helpful if you provide some code or idea so we can identify the problem or what u already tried

Comment: the session storage can save your data irrespective of windows or url it will stored on a variable on session which you can use on any window or any url within the server

Comment: I dont have any code at the moment. But what I could is going to do is to read an element from Page B (which is open in a different tab or window, for example assume I am going to read an element from Yahoo.com) and then refresh that page (Yahoo.com) every couple of minutes to recheck the element.